# Is there a Faster way to Clear a Custom Cache Using the cacheGetSession Object?

Tags: coldfusion, ehcache, coldfusion-9

I know I can use ColdFusion cache APIs to clear data as such:

```
<cfset cacheName = "custom">
<cfset ids = cacheGetAllIds(cacheName)>
<cfset cacheRemove(arrayToList(ids), false, cacheName)>
```

But in practice retrieving all the ids (i.e. `cacheGetAllIds()`) to do the deletion is slow (e.g. seconds). Where I'm thinking there should be a way if I'm completely starting over to have this happen in milliseconds. In my particular case the custom cache is disk persistent and can be 100s of megabytes on disk.

I'm suspecting there's a faster way to clear this out using methods on `cacheGetSession()`, perhaps in conjunction with ColdFusion APIs. So asking to see if someone has some knowledge of how to do this, ***and*** make ColdFusion happy at the same time, before I start looking under the hood myself.

**Update**

Looks like it might be possible to use [cacheGetSession](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSd160b5fdf5100e8f-7018704d129d9eeda9f-8000.html)(cacheName, true).removeAll() because the object returned is of type [net.sf.ehcache.Cache](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html), which implements [net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Ehcache.html). And this interface specifies a method removeAll(). Haven't tried it out yet though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does it:

```
cacheGetSession(cacheName, true).removeAll()
```

With about 10K+ records it returned in 60 ms.

FYI: cachGetSession() is a ColdFusion 9.0.1 function

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but is this any faster?  Just in case `ArrayToList()` is the bottleneck.

```
<cfloop index="cache" array="#cacheGetAllIds(cacheName)#">
    <cfset cacheRemove(cache, false, cacheName)>
</cfloop>
```

reference: http://www.aaronwest.net/blog/index.cfm/2009/11/28/14-Days-of-ColdFusion-9-Caching-Day-12--Removing-All-Items-in-Cache

If performance is really an issue for you, file a bug report? http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html

Comment: cacheGetAllIds() is the bottleneck - actually if you look at the API docs on the Cache object for getKeys() it describes the algorithm for retrieval as O(n) as 8ms per 1000 entries, what I'm seeing is slower - 2000ms+ for 10,000+ entries.

Comment: Would setting cacheSetProperties({maxElementsInMemory=0},cacheName) then restoring it to the size work??